# Why a python library can download needed modules but java can't?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In some libraries like selenium we can download necessary library or module from code like download Chrome driver or Firefox driver in easy way, but in java code we don't.

We need to download manually and add to the path in project or system environment and after that use it in code providing a path for the library or execute environment.

Java code example:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Python code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

as you see the driver can download from python but java need to downloaded and placed somewhere in environment and than use it in code.

Am I wrong or misunderstanding?

chat gpt answer:

> You are correct in your understanding. In Java, when using libraries like Selenium, you typically need to manually download the necessary driver executable (e.g., ChromeDriver or GeckoDriver for Firefox) and specify its location in your code or system environment.
>
> Unlike Python, where you can easily install and manage drivers through package managers like pip, Java requires a manual approach for managing the driver executables.
>
> In your Java code example, you can see that you need to set the system property "webdriver.chrome.driver" to the location of the downloaded ChromeDriver executable. This tells the Selenium library where to find the driver on your system.
>
> Once you have downloaded the appropriate driver executable and provided the correct path, you can create an instance of the driver (e.g., ChromeDriver) and configure any desired options before using it to interact with web pages.
>
> Although the process may seem more involved in Java compared to Python, it allows for greater flexibility in managing different versions of the driver and ensuring compatibility with your browser.
>
> In summary, your understanding is correct. Java requires manual downloading and placement of the driver executable, while Python provides a more streamlined approach for downloading and managing drivers through package managers.

Comment: Are you asking why the Selenium developers did it differently in Python and Java? We can't answer that. Ask them.

Comment: nope I'm looking for some way to do it in code like python. have you? The selenium is just an example

Answer (score 1):

Your understand is incorrect, so is ChatGPT's answer.

With selenium `v4.6.0` and onwards (IRRESPECTIVE OF BINDING LANGUAGE, BE IT JAVA, PYTHON, C# etc.), setting up the `driver.exe` is not mandatory. Selenium's inbuilt tool known as [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will handle/download the drivers programmatically.

Just like your Python code, Java code also can be as simple as:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Below line is not mandatory anymore, if you specify, it will take `driver.exe` from the provided path, else Selenium will download and use it internally.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I had no idea Selenium could do that nowadays. That's very convenient!

Comment: So you said we can do it, but the programmer of library need to do it?

Comment: Programmer of the library has already implemented this feature in selenium `v4.6.0` and above. This tool is available to all binding languages like Java, Python etc. [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: It's work your example. but the Question is not about one libraries, about what can we do for all libraries that we have like python as do it with.And thanks for reply

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your above comment!

Comment: My question is, in java like python have any library management  or module that can control the code libraries ? maven do it in best way but if you need execute file it can not management for you.